# How can I get the hyperlink address from a cell in an Excel spreadsheet using Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m

Given this table:

[image]

How can I use Power Query to display the underlying URL address for the hyperlink in each cell?

Pulling in the table as source just brings in "google" and "bing." I'd like to get to the "https://www.google.com" and "https://www.bing.com" that underly them. Can I do that?

Comment: Not sure this is very easy. Looks like VBA is needed to extract the URL: https://superuser.com/questions/593492/can-i-use-an-excel-formula-to-extract-the-link-location-of-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell/593493

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. I was afraid VBA would be the answer...but really hoping for a "clean" Power Query solution.